# Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions, then which of these is correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

a) if $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for every $x$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int^{x+1}_x(f(t)-g(t))dt=0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0$. 
b) if $f(x)$ is increasing and $g(x)\le f(x) \le g(x) + \frac {1}{x}$ for every $x>1$, then there exists $N>1$ such that $g(x)$ increases in $(N,\infty)$. 
c) if $g(x)\le f(x) \le g(x) + \frac {1}{x}$ for every $x>1$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int^{x+\sqrt {x}}_x(f(t)-g(t))dt=0$. 
d) if $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, then atleast one of $f(x),g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$. 
My "Work": 
a) this was my selected answer, based on intuition (hopefully doesn't fail me this time), what the integral at $x\to \infty$ is calculating the area between the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, so if it's going to zero, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be going to the same limit at infinity, otherwise there will be some area between the functions, and the integral won't be zero. 
b) I took a counter example $f(x)=g(x)=-\frac {1}{x}$, but looking at it again, this function isn't continuous so this doesn't work. 
c) No idea how to approach, couldn't decide between this and (a). but wen't with (a) based on intuition again which I hate to do but I really had no option, since this one looks at "bigger area at infinity ($x+\sqrt {x}$). 
d) I thought of $f(x),g(x)=|x|$, so $h(x)=|x|^2=x^2$, would love to hear feedback if this works as a counter example. 
Note: This question was in my exam, it stunned me and these were my thoughts and everything I did, it would really mean alot to me if someone can help me understand how to approach this question in a better way other than intuition. please be gentle while telling me I got the wrong answer if I did :). 
Any help and feedback and explanation is really really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Cuhrazatee What are you talking about? For (d) it is the perfect counterexample. Having neither differentiable at $x=0$ is the goal.

Comment: General suggestion for the first parts: You can reduce to the case $g=0$. Now, for example, if $\int_n^{n+1} f(t)\,dt \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, can you conclude that $f\to 0$? Draw some pictures — e.g., of little triangles.

Comment: @TedShifrin What I'm thinking is like we're getting the area of the rectangle that has $n+1-n=1$ width on the $x$ axis, so we're getting $1*f(x)$ or something like that, What I thought about is that if the integral limit is going to zero ,that means $1*f(x)$ is very close to zero, seems like this is wrong but I'm not understanding it well

Comment: Too vague. Draw triangles with height $1$ and bases going to $0$.